# How to change default Backbone Dynamic form layout

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-forms

In our application we are using backbone dynamic forms.
By default Backbone dynamic forms display "label inputfield" approach. Can we update the default layout dynamic form which appends one more field like "label inputfield inputfield". If possible how to do that?

For Ex: 
Name textfield textfield

First textfield is for entering description of the label
Second textfield is for entering value of the label

Comment: Have you tried the `List` dataType?

Comment: I want the solution for the below link. Its the same usecase which i need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816976/using-customized-layouts-and-variable-no-of-fields-with-backbone-forms @Seebiscuit